# Why does Stack Overflow Careers need access to private Bitbucket repositories?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, jobs

When I try to link my public CV to my [Bitbucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) account I get this message:

```
StackOverflow is requesting access to your data

StackOverflow is requesting read and write access to your public and private 
repositories. If you don't want to give StackOverflow access to your data, 
exit this page.
```

Is there a way to link the data, but keep private repositories private?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hi Joe, we only do this to verify identity, and that the repositories are yours. We have no interest in writing to your repository, it's just that Bitbucket's API is all-or-nothing when it comes to authentication.

We will no longer display private repositories in the import list, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Matt.

Comment: @M'vy they answered the question and the import list does show private repos, but at least it's only to select the private ones.

Comment: Matt, is this just a one time thing during the verification? You don't keep write access forever do you?

Comment: Thanks, Matt -- I can't upvote this because, well, you know, but I would.

Any chance this information can be added to the profile page itself, maybe in a tooltip or somesuch? It's just a little creepy to be prompted for r/w access to all repos, and a ready explanation would ease the mind of the newcomer.

Comment: Requesting more permissions than what is needed is unnecessary, potentially dangerous (just imagine someone gaining control over the relevant server) and makes concerned users suspicious about StackOverflow's intentions. As long as this behavior is present I won't be able to use this feature. I would really appreciate if you would talk to the BitBucket guys and request to change this.

Comment: Doesn't read permissions on private repos sound too much? Why should S.O. read the source? Or am I totally out of this scope and I owe a sorry?

Comment: @JimmyKane: It does sound too much - and it is. But Stack Exchange can't control this. That's the whole point of this answer. You don't owe anyone an apology - perhaps Bitbucket does instead.

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to confirm my identity, but I would never give you write permission to my repos (nothing personal! it just looks too insecure). I know this is Bitbucket's fault, but from your side you could add a tag saying "unverified" for instance, or check for a special SE repo with your id number on it.