# How do I list a bitbucket project without granting private access to my account?

Tags: support, jobs

I'm aware of this question: [Why does Stack Overflow Careers need access to private Bitbucket repositories?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90732/why-does-stackoverflow-careers-need-access-to-private-bitbucket-repos)

I'm not willing to do this. How can I add a link to my bitbucket project to the 'Open Source' section of my profile? I've opened a [bug](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/3318/oauth-privileges-too-broad) with bitbucket.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, but if you aren't willing to grant OAuth access to bitbucket we won't let you add bitbucket repos to your profile.

We require OAuth authentication for all the source control services that provide it as a way to keep people from gaming (mainly misrepresenting themselves by adding projects that don't belong to them) the open source section of the profile.

We'll keep an eye on that bug report and update our permission request when they offer read only permissions (we don't want to have write access to your repos either).

Comment: IMO, encouraging users to grant overly broad permissions is a bad idea. I think that requiring OAuth for all services that provide it _with reasonable permissions_ would be a better policy, but I understand your desire to reduce gaming.