# Career site asks for too much permission when adding BitBucket info

Tags: support, status-bydesign, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Does Stackoverflow Careers need access to private bitbucket repos?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90732/why-does-stackoverflow-careers-need-access-to-private-bitbucket-repos)

I wanted to add a BitBucket project to my career page and was redirected to the BitBucket site where the following message was displayed:

> StackOverflow is requesting read and write access to your public and private repositories.

Is it really necessary to request full access to all repositories? It seems a bit excessive and is not a permission most people would grant.

Comment: Comes down to the same core BitBucket issue as http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90732/89334

Comment: The truth is, during their downtime, the Careers dev team will pitch in on some of your private projects.

Comment: Jeff wants to get hold of the keys to as many bitbuckets as possible in order to build the new SE archive there. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73226/set-up-an-archive-for-legendary-deleted-questions/73377#comment177151_73377

Comment: I don't think this is something to be joking about. Requesting more permissions than what is needed is unnecessary, potentially dangerous (just imagine someone gaining control over the relevant server) and makes concerned users suspicious about StackOverflow's intentions. As long as this behavior is present I won't be able to use this feature.